# Get ajax response from submit button

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I´m testing with Nightwatch.js. Is there a way tho get the ajax response from a submit click event?
Thanks in advance

html:

```
<form id="login-form" method="POST" action="companyUrl/api/resetpin" style="display: block;">
```

Comment: Be more clear, please. What do you mean "get the ajax response"?

Comment: can you explain your problem?

Comment: That action returns a pin code that I want to insert on the next pop up window. The problem here is,`var request = require('request');
var pinCode = '';

request.post({
        json : true,
        url:companyUrl/api/resetpin',
        form: {msisdn:'msisdnNumber'}
    },

    function(err,httpResponse,body){
        pinCode = body.pin;
        return console.log('pin number: ' + pinCode);

    }` return a pincode, but in the test code after you click on submit button it resets the pin again causing the error. I want the resetpin to be done only once

Comment: pleasepost the block of code and  an image with page elements(where you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create an javascript method which holds your ajax code and call this method onSubmit of the form!